# Need help scraping a website in perl

Tags: perl, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am new into the world of perl and right now I am trying to scrape a webpage. I have done some scraping before and used `WWW::Mechanize`. The pages that I scraped before were somehow simple, so I took the page source and then extracted the data I needed from there. But now I have a different website that seems to contain frames. http://www.usgbc-illinois.org/membership/directory/
I am not asking for any code, but some ideas or modules I could use to extract data from the website above.

Thank1s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find some useful information on this website [Web Scraping](http://blogs.perl.org/users/stas/2013/01/web-scraping-with-modern-perl-part-1.html) and also you can take look at this module [Web Scraper Module](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/Web-Scraper-0.38/lib/Web/Scraper.pm)